# Send user input to controller's parameter

Tags: laravel

I am working on a laravel project where I have orders, and I would like people to type in their order code and their order will appear. I am struggling to find a solution to let my controller's function 'show' know which order to show.

**TrackController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;

class TrackController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('track.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);
        return view('track.show',[
            'order' => $order
        ]);
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/track', 'TrackController@index');
Route::get('/track/{id}', 'TrackController@show');
```

**track.index**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content center">
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TrackController@show', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <input type="number" name="input-order-track-id" id="order-track-id" value="">
            {{ Form::button('Track', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

So my question is: How do I put my form so I can send the user's input as a variable to my 'show' function?

EDIT: I tried making a redirect function, but I keep getting the output 'Order not found.'

**TrackController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;

class TrackController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('track.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::where('code', $id);
        return view('track.show',[
            'order' => $order
        ]);
    }

    public function redirect(Request $request)
    {
        $orders = Order::all();
        $orderCode = $request->input('order-track-id');
        if($orders->contains('code', $orderCode)){
            return redirect('/track/' . $orderCode);
        } else{
            return redirect('/track')->with('error', 'Order not found.');
        }
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/track', 'TrackController@index');
Route::post('/track/redirect', 'TrackController@redirect');
Route::get('/track/{id}', 'TrackController@show');
```

**track.index**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content center">
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TrackController@redirect', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <input type="number" name="input-order-track-id" id="order-track-id">
            {{ Form::button('Track', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

EDIT 2:

Changed my TrackController, but now it keeps aborting to the 404 page, even though I enter a code that is present in the 'code' column in my 'orders' table

**TrackController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;

class TrackController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('track.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::where('code', $id)->first();
        return view('track.show',[
            'order' => $order
        ]);
    }

    public function redirect(Request $request)
    {
        $orderCode = $request->input('order-track-id');
        $order = Order::where('code', $orderCode)->first();
        if(!$order){
            abort(404);
        }else{
            return response()->redirect('/track/' . $order->code);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't `POST` to that route, so your form will not work. If you need to use your input, you need to define a function to redirect to that route with the input appended, like `http://myapp/track/value`, where `value` was entered into your `<input>`, then appended to the URL. It's a bit broad, but see what you can figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured I'd need to do something like that. I've edited my original post with my redirect function but it's not working, could you take a look?

Comment: You make the way complex.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using the `Orders::all()` as it will fetch all the rows from the table. So, what you can do is `$order = Order::where('code',$orderCode)->first();`. After this you can check like this

```
if(!$order){
 abort(404);
}else{
 return response()->redirect('/track/'.$order->code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my TrackController, but it keeps aborting to the 404 page even though the code that I enter is present in my orders table. Can you check if you spot any mistakes?

Comment: first check if you are able to fetch the order with the code from the request. use the tinker tool to test this